# I need to access an property inside an object but it always comes back as undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm using Javascript inside a React component.

I want to access a certain property of an object.

So if I write this object out to the console like this:

```
console.log("Engine: ", this.Engine);
```

I get this:

```
Engine:
        child { ... }
          attributes:
               id: 293
               manufactureer: "Ford"
               date: "2012-02-18"
               location: "Michigan"
               modelsUsed:
                  usedByMustang: true
                  usedByF150: true
                  usedByFusion: false
               source: "f9919"
               typeName: "Coyote"
```

If I write out something like this: `console.log("Engine Type Name: ", this.Engine.attributes.typeName);`

I get this: `Engine Type Name: Coyote`

That's great, but I just want to check one property buried deep down, the one called `usedByMustang` that's inside the `modelsUsed` array.

So I tried all these:

```
console.log("Engine - usedByMustang: ", this.Engine.attributes.usedByMustang);
console.log("Engine - usedByMustang: ", this.Engine.attributes.modelsUsed.usedByMustang);
console.log("Engine - usedByMustang: ", this.Engine.attributes.modelsUsed[0]);
```

They all come back as `undefined`

Is there a way to access the properties I want?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried console.log("Engine - usedByMustang: ", this.Engine.attributes.modelsUsed[0].usedByMustang); ?

Comment: This structure is hard to read like this, follow Platus suggestion or do a `console.log(JSON.stringify(this.Engine, null, 2))` and you should able to see what is your mistake in the object structure, or either post the result back here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you should try checking down to `modelsUsed` first and see if it even has those 3 items in it first.
Try this first `console.log("Engine - Check for modelsUsed: ", this.Engine.attributes.modelsUsed);`

then try this `console.log("Engine - usedByMustang: ", this.Engine.attributes.modelsUsed && this.Engine.attributes.modelsUsed.usedByMustang );`